# Using nested for loops to print numbers in 6x7 grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

im writing a program which accepts any number, n, where -6<n<2. The program will print out the numbers from n to n+41, in a 6x7 grid (6 columns, 7 numbers). I strictly have to use nested for loops. Im new in python and would appreciate it if you helped me with simple code.

This is what i have come up with.

```
n = eval(input("Enter a number between -6 and 2:\n"))
if -6<n<2:
    for r in range(6):
        for c in range(7):
            for i in range (n, n+7):
                n += 1
                print(i, end=" ")
            print("")
```

This is my desired output.

```
Enter a number between -6 and 2:
-2
-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31 32
33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

**My question is how can i restrict the numbers to stop at n+41 (which in this case is 39 since input is -2)? look at disaster output below!!**

This is the disaster i made:

```
Enter a number between -6 and 2:
-2
-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 
47 48 49 50 51 52 53 
54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 
68 69 70 71 72 73 74 
75 76 77 78 79 80 81 
82 83 84 85 86 87 88 
89 90 91 92 93 94 95 
96 97 98 99 100 101 102 
103 104 105 106 107 108 109 
110 111 112 113 114 115 116 
117 118 119 120 121 122 123 
124 125 126 127 128 129 130 
131 132 133 134 135 136 137 
138 139 140 141 142 143 144 
145 146 147 148 149 150 151 
152 153 154 155 156 157 158 
159 160 161 162 163 164 165 
166 167 168 169 170 171 172 
173 174 175 176 177 178 179 
180 181 182 183 184 185 186 
187 188 189 190 191 192 193 
194 195 196 197 198 199 200 
201 202 203 204 205 206 207 
208 209 210 211 212 213 214 
215 216 217 218 219 220 221 
222 223 224 225 226 227 228 
229 230 231 232 233 234 235 
236 237 238 239 240 241 242 
243 244 245 246 247 248 249 
250 251 252 253 254 255 256 
257 258 259 260 261 262 263 
264 265 266 267 268 269 270 
271 272 273 274 275 276 277 
278 279 280 281 282 283 284 
285 286 287 288 289 290 291
```

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `for c in range(7):` loop

Comment: but does that loop not handle the number of columns?

Comment: `for i in range (n, n+7)` also handles the columns so you have to chose betwnen the two

Comment: FWIW, there's no reason to use `eval` here when `int` would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are having 3 nested loop, but only need 2:

```py
n = -2
for row in range(6):
    for col in range(7):
        print(n, end=" ")
        n += 1
    print()
```

Output:

```
-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Comment: oh, I see what I did wrong. if I may I ask, why did you assign n to -3?

Comment: It is just an example. It should be -2 btw.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there but you have two loops that manage columns. You should only have one:

```
n = eval(input("Enter a number between -6 and 2:\n"))
if -6<n<2:
    for r in range(6):
        for i in range (n, n+7):
            n += 1
            print(i, end=" ")
        print("")
```

or

```
n = eval(input("Enter a number between -6 and 2:\n"))
if -6<n<2:
    for r in range(6):
        for c in range(7):
            print(n, end=" ")  # print n here, before increasing it
            n += 1
        print("")
```

Another approach would be to go through the numbers by steps of 7 and print a range of 7 in one print statement per line:

```
n = eval(input("Enter a number between -6 and 2:\n"))
if -6<n<2:
    for v in range(n,n+42,7): # n, n+7, n+14, n+21, n+28, n+35
        print(*range(v,v+7))  # v+0, v+1, v+2 ... v+6
```